# One ShipStation Plugin - 404 Error - UPDATED 14-07-17

Tags: plugins, url, shipping

I'm currently looking to implement the One ShipStation plugin for my Craft Commerce site.

I went through the Custom store settings on Shipstation.com, making sure they matched the settings in the Plugin settings page.

Shipstation requires a XML page to work, and the One Shipstation provides the URL "https://www.mywebsite.com/actions/oneShipStation/orders/process"

Testing the Connection from Shipstation's side is unsuccessful, and returns a <del>404 error, saying that the URL cannot be found.</del>

**UPDATE:**

I made a few changes, and no longer receive a 404 error. This change came from changing some of the NGINX configurations for my site.

First I changed

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

to

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

Then I made sure that all url inquiries were being redirected to https, which cleared up some other issues I was having.

I am now receiving a 500 error, and this is what the log spits out

```
2017/07/11 15:21:53 [error] [php] Trying to get property of non-object (/var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php:108)
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php(266): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->valueFromMappingAndModel()
#1 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php(117): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->mapCraftModel()
#2 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php(91): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->item()
#3 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php(66): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->items()
#4 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php(22): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->order()
#5 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/controllers/OneShipStation_OrdersController.php(65): Craft\OneShipStation_XmlService->orders()
#6 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/controllers/OneShipStation_OrdersController.php(22): Craft\Oneshipstation_OrdersController->getOrders()
#7 unknown(0): Craft\Oneshipstation_OrdersController->actionProcess()
#8 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#9 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CInlineAction->runWithParamsInternal()
#10 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#11 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): Craft\Oneshipstation_OrdersController->runAction()
#12 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): Craft\Oneshipstation_OrdersController->runActionWithFilters()
#13 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): Craft\Oneshipstation_OrdersController->run()
#14 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(817): Craft\WebApp->runController()
#15 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(287): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#16 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#17 /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/app/index.php(62): Craft\WebApp->run()
#18 /var/www/mywebsite.com/public/index.php(19): require_once()
REQUEST_URI=/actions/oneShipStation/orders/process?SS-UserName=username&SS-Password=p@$$w0rd&action=export&start_date=07%2f11%2f2017+15%3a16&end_date=07%2f11%2f2017+15%3a21&page=1
```

Which points to this portion of the plugin's services, specifically the line that starts "$item_mapping = ..."

```
public function item(\SimpleXMLElement $xml, Commerce_LineItemModel $item, $name='Item') {
        $item_xml = $xml->getName() == $name ? $xml : $xml->addChild($name);

        $item_mapping = ['SKU'              => ['callback' => function($item) { return $item->getPurchasable()->sku; }],
                         'Name'             => 'description',
                         'Weight'           => ['callback' => function($item) { return round($item->weight, 2); },
                                                'cdata' => false],
                         'Quantity'         => ['field' => 'qty',
                                                'cdata' => false],
                         'UnitPrice'        => ['callback' => function($item) { return round($item->salePrice, 2); },
                                                'cdata' => false]
        ];
        $this->mapCraftModel($item_xml, $item_mapping, $item);

        $item_xml->addChild('WeightUnits', 'Grams');

        if (isset($item->snapshot['options'])) {
            $option_xml = $this->options($item_xml, $item->snapshot['options']);
        }

        return $item_xml;
    }
```

I believe the previous error may have resulted from an incomplete order model, which may have been resolved by a colleague working on another portion of the site.

**UPDATE 14-07-17:**

The 500 error I now receive is the following.

```
Call to undefined function Craft\dom_import_simplexml() in /var/www/mywebsite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php:404
```

Comment: Only thing I can answer is the last "is action a protected parameter now?" and the answer is no. :)  There is an actionTrigger config setting that is set to "actions" by default: https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#actionTrigger

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using an out of date version of the plugin. Can you try updating to the latest and see if you're still getting this error? https://github.com/onedesign/oneshipstation/archive/master.zip

Comment: I just downloaded the updated version of the plugin and can confirm that I'm seeing the same error.

Comment: I too have downloaded the latest version of the plugin, and am running into the current error.

"Call to undefined function Craft\dom_import_simplexml() in /var/www/mysite.com/craft/plugins/oneshipstation/services/OneShipStation_XmlService.php:404"

Comment: @P.Stucker Sounds like your server doesn't have the DOM extension installed and the plugin is using it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: It may sound like that, but when I go to my i.php, DOM shows as listed. Thoughts?